# Heterogen(e)ous collections in CoreData

Tags: swift, core-data, data-modeling

So I'm building a music player, and I'm modelling my data and I'm not sure whether I have a good way of handling my current case.

I have `Artist`, `Album`, `Disc`, and `Track` entities, and I want to be able to create ordered `Playlist`s containing any of the others.

Modelling in pure Swift I would have something like:

```swift
struct Playlist {
    enum Segment {
        case track(Track)
        case disc(Disc)
        case album(Album)
        case artist(Artist)
    }
    
    let segments: [Segment]
}
```

AFAICT my options are either to have multiple entities (e.g. `PlaylistArtistIndexJoin`) which would let me work purely in the Swift-side objects,

Or I could have a `PlaylistSegment` table in CoreData with:

- `Playlist`
- an `index` integer,
- a `segmentType` field, and
- a raw `ID` integer looking into the appropriate entity

and then loading the segment array by walking the index and looking up the correct entity based on the `segmentType` and e.g. calling `Artist.from(id:)`

The first method would require me to build the eventual `segments` array by either:

- scanning each join table in turn with a temporary array that could handle the holes, and then convert it at the end to the real array, or
- walking the `index`, scanning the different tables until you find the one with the right index before appending to a normal array

The second method has no foreign key relation for the `ID`, so leaves me open to a `Track` being deleted but the playlist could still refer to it.

Opinions, options I didn't consider?

Comment: You can’t have a playlist of artists that doesn’t make sense to me, a playlist contains only one thing and that is songs (tracks). I think you are mixing playlists and some kind of filtering in your design

Comment: With respect, the playlist will be converted to a tracklist when it is enqueued, at which point all tracks by the identified artist will be enqueued, meaning that future tracks are automatically added

Comment: Ok so what you call a playlist is what I call a filter (or dynamic playlist) then, a slight misunderstanding on my part. I guess you need to-many relationships with all the other entities then in your Playlist.